# Dynamically load content from jsp resultset in Div

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I am not sure the best way to go about this, basically I have a JSP page that returns a set of results (a list of employees) in HTML from a MySQL database.  Using a loop, each item is returned and formated into a link.  Eg.

```
<a href="details.jsp?emp=\"" + resultSet.getString(1) + "\"/>"
```

Therefore each link will allow a user to load a page that will display the details of the selected employee.

I now want to improve this.  I have a `div` on the results page that I would like to populate with the employee details instead of opening a new link.  My problem is, I do not know how to go about this using jQuery.  I have looked at `.load()` but that seems to only work with a predefined address and when using `.click(#div_id)`, how could jQuery know what employee details to load?

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I am still learning.  Can anyone suggest where I should look or how I could go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="details.jsp?emp=123" class="employeeLink"/>

<div id="results"></div>


<script>
$(function () {
  $("a.employeeLink").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#results").load($(this).attr("href"));


  });

});
</script>
```